# C++ unable to store aligned string in a string variable and print it

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with string alignments.

i am trying to print a receipt of a food orders with food names stored in multi dimensional array (full_menu), price(double price) and quantity(int quantity).At the end of the function these variable are converted to string and appended in a string variable (orders).After the loop ends then it gets printed out.Please ignore calculation of the total price of each order.It will be done later.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <typeinfo>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    void menu() {
    string full_menu [3][6] = {{"A. Chicken",
    "1.chicken leg barbecue",
    "2.general chicken",
    "3.chicken liver abodo",
    "4.buffalo wings",
    "5.Permesan wings"},

    {"B. Soup",
    "1.mushroom soup",
    "2.cream of corn soup",
    "3.hototay soup",
    "4.Papaitan soup",
    "5.Bulalo soup"},

    {"C. Beverages",
    "1.coke",
    "2.diet coke",
    "3.cherry coke",
    "4.sprite",
    "5.Aqua-Panna"
    }};
    for(int parent=0; parent<3; parent++)
    {
        for(int child=0;child<6;child++)
        {
            cout<<full_menu[parent][child]<<endl;
        }
    }

//user select the choices and quantity
    string orders;
    int quantity;
    double price;
    for (int i =0; i <=i ;i++) {
        //food_name//
        cout << "Enter your orders(example A1 or b3: ";
        int main_menu_number=0;
        char main_menu;
        int sub_menu = 0;
        cin >> main_menu;
        if (main_menu == 'a' || main_menu == 'A') {
            main_menu_number = 0;
        } else if (main_menu == 'b' || main_menu == 'B') {
            main_menu_number = 1;
        } else if (main_menu == 'c' || main_menu == 'C') {
            main_menu_number = 2;
        } else if(main_menu=='x'||main_menu=='X'){
            break;
        }
        cin>>sub_menu;
        //price//
        if (main_menu_number==0&&sub_menu==1){
            price=5.00;
        } else if(main_menu_number==0&&sub_menu==2) {
            price=7.00;
        }else if(main_menu_number==0&&sub_menu==3) {
            price=5.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==0&&sub_menu==4) {
            price=8.00;
        }else if(main_menu_number==0&&sub_menu==5) {
            price=7.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==1&&sub_menu==1) {
            price=4.00;
        }else if(main_menu_number==1&&sub_menu==2) {
            price=5.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==1&&sub_menu==3) {
            price=7.00;
        }else if(main_menu_number==1&&sub_menu==4) {
            price=8.00;
        }else if(main_menu_number==1&&sub_menu==5) {
            price=7.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==2&&sub_menu==1) {
            price=1.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==2&&sub_menu==2) {
            price=1.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==2&&sub_menu==3) {
            price=1.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==2&&sub_menu==4) {
            price=1.50;
        }else if(main_menu_number==2&&sub_menu==5) {
            price=0.30;
        }
        cout<<"Enter quantity :";
        cin>>quantity;
        orders.append(full_menu[main_menu_number][sub_menu]+"    "+to_string(quantity)+"    "+to_string(price)+"\n");
    }
    cout<<orders;
}



int main()
{
    menu();
}
```

The output is

```
A. Chicken
1.chicken leg barbecue
2.general chicken
3.chicken liver abodo
4.buffalo wings
5.Permesan wings
B. Soup
1.mushroom soup
2.cream of corn soup
3.hototay soup
4.Papaitan soup
5.Bulalo soup
C. Beverages
1.coke
2.diet coke
3.cherry coke
4.sprite
5.Aqua-Panna
Enter your orders(example A1 or b3:a1
 a1
Enter quantity :2
2
Enter your orders(example A1 or b3:c3
 c3
Enter quantity :2
2
Enter your orders(example A1 or b3:x
 x
1.chicken leg barbecue    2    5.000000
3.cherry coke    2    1.500000
```

The expected output i am trying to make is :

```
1.chicken leg barbecue    2    5.000000
3.cherry coke             2    1.500000
```

please suggest.

Comment: Where in your code do you make the number of spaces after the name depend on the length of the name?

Comment: You just have a string with 4 spaces as the separator. How is that supposed to align the next column?

Comment: i tried the code below orders.append(full_menu[main_menu_number][sub_menu]<<setw(5)<<to_string(quantity)<<setw(5)<<to_string(price)+"\n"); but ut shows error - binary operator '<<' can't be applied to the expressions of type 'string' and '_Setw'

Comment: The `<<` operator and functions like `setw()` are used with output streams, not when concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `std::stringstream` so you can use the output operators on it, rather than a `std::string`.

You also need to use `setw()` before the item name, to make them all the same width.

```
std::stringstream orders;
...
orders << setw(20) << full_menu[main_menu_number][sub_menu] << setw(5) << quantity << setw(5) << price << "\n";
```

Then you can print the final result with:

```
cout << orders.str();
```

Comment: but your suggestion helped im trying to change the setw() digits and see if i can make it work thank you.

Comment: You need to use `setw()` before the item name to sets its width.